# My Build File run successfully but It didnot change the output when I update my source code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-emulator

I'm working in react native 17.0.2. The problem is that when I updated my source code It didn't update the output in the emulator.

If anyone knows why it's happened please tell me

Answer (score 1):

On windows, press Ctrl + M on emulator and enable hot reloading, now when you save the source code , output will be reflected in the emulator

Comment: I try it But it did'nt work